Trying to load symbols for a VSDiagnostics report (diagsession) doesn't have any results
I am trying to run diagnostics from commandline as a test so I can then move on to profile our production app with production data. I'm following this guide for collecting data
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profile-apps-from-command-line?view=vs-2022
Locally what I am doing is

I Clean->build my whole solution and running the application from
the output folder.

I start the diagnostics session and point it to
the process ID of my running application.

I do some stuff here and there and then stop the profiling session.

I open the report file and it fails to load symbols.

I then go to Debug->options->Symbols and add a new symbol file location to the path of the output folder (from where I run the application in step 1)


And yet it still fails to find symbols, what am I doing wrong? What am I missing?
